# Angular material tree expand a particular node

Tags: angular, tree, angular-material2, expand

I have seen various examples to expand all nodes in mat-tree using

```
expandAll()
```

Is there any mechanism to expand a particular node if we click on it. Something like

```
node.expand()
```

I had referred angular material documentation but not got any answer. Please guide if anyone gone through it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `expand` method on `treeControl`, which operates on the `treeControl.dataNodes` array.

Something like

```
this.treeControl.expand(this.treeControl.dataNodes[/** node you want to expand **/]);
```

Just keep in mind that if you want to expand a particular node, all its ancestors up to the root need to be expanded as well.

---

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yi9tbm)

Comment: How to expand all parent node of particular child node in nested tree control in angular 8??? I used this code with some extra fields modification https://stackblitz.com/angular/dklgxbrynad?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-nested-overview-example.ts

Comment: What is I want to pass in a specific node to open that was clicked. How do I do that. I cannot pass the node because your sollution need index.