# How to expand material nested tree to specific node?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm struggling with expanding tree with NestedTreeControl to specific node.
In included stackblitz i want to expand nodes 'Vegetables' and 'Green' to see node 'Broccoli'.
Can some help please?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-icfxva?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-nested-overview-example.ts)

Comment: Please can you check this link I think this is an aswer of your question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55590162/angular-material-tree-expand-a-particular-node

Comment: Thanks for reply, I checked it before posting and i know about this method. And if I manuly call these 'expanders' it works. But when I only have some id of object in bottom of hierarchy i need recursion to manully open his parents, right? Can you help? :-)

Comment: After few hours of hard pain I ended with this this working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-icfxva?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-nested-overview-example.ts but I'm 100% sure it can be written better way.. anayone?

Comment: Great, I see It is working correctly,

Comment: And on the real project if you want to collapse the previous tabs I think you need to  call `this.treeControl.collapseAll();` before call `this.exp()`