# how to wait for children load to complete when expanding a dynamically-loaded nested tree node

Tags: angular, angular-material, tree, nested

I am quite new to angular, so I'm sure I am just missing something fairly straightforward here, but I haven't found an example anywhere of what I am doing to answer my question.

I am successfully dynamically loading branches in a *nested* angular material tree using a service.  I do this by defining a 'loadChildren' function which makes the service call to populate the children array, tied in to my NestedTreeControl object when it is instantiated, basically:

```
public nestedTreeControl: NestedTreeControl<Treenode>;
. . .
  constructor() {
    this.nestedTreeControl = new NestedTreeControl<Treenode>(this.loadChildren);
```

and wrapping my ng-container with an ngIf test so nested components aren't instantiated until fully loaded:

```
            <ul *ngIf="nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(tnode) && tnode.childrenLoaded">
                <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
            </ul>
```

This has been working perfectly in my UI for expanding and loading children dynamically.  But I am trying to add a utility function to recursively expand nodes when I have an ordered array of known 'nodeId' values (a parameter that is part of the *Treenode* object above) but the nodeIds in the list may not all be loaded if all nodes in the path are not yet expanded in my tree.

So I have a recursive function, similar to what is shown in the *exp()* method here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-icfxva?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-nested-overview-example.ts, which I found from a comment on this post: ([How to expand material nested tree to specific node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59161690/how-to-expand-material-nested-tree-to-specific-node)).

If I have previously expanded my tree within my UI to include all the nodeIds in the ordered search array, my function works great.  But since my children load dynamically as I expand a node, when I go to expand a non-expanded node (i.e., `nestedTreeControl.expand(tnode)` (or in the stackblitz example, `treeControl.expand(node)`), I need to wait for the children to load before making my recursive call and passing in the list of child nodes.

I'm not sure how to go about 'waiting' for the children to load within my recursive function before making the next call.  What/how can I tie in to the NestedTreeControl to figure out when the children have completed loading for a newly-expanded node (i.e., when my node's 'childrenLoaded' flag has finally been set to 'true')?

Comment: I should clarify...when I load the first (root) level of nodes, the result includes an array of children objects appropriate for the root level nodes, but each of those child objects have empty 'children' arrays.  So when a node is expanded, 'loadChildren' goes out and loads each of the expanded node's child objects from the service so we have each child's children array populated.  I'm limited to doing that by the service result, which is used in other applications.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer after working on this for a bit.  I ended up adding an EventEmitter instance that is emitted in the loadChildren method once the children are completely loaded.

In my recursive function, I am subscribing to the new event and waiting to recursively call itself until the event has been received, but only if the 'childrenLoaded' flag has not yet been set on my node object, and I do that check/subscription immediately before expanding the node if it is not expanded.  For all other cases (children previously loaded, whether expanding or not), I do not subscribe but do the recursive call immediately.

In addition, instead of passing back the eventually-found node in my recrusive function, I am emitting a second EventEmitter that the original first-caller to the recursive function is subscribing to.

This seems to be working very well for deeply nested, dynamically loaded trees.

Answer (score 0):

In principle you could do this:

```js
async function expandToNode(node: TreeNode, p: (n: TreeNode) => boolean): Promise<void> {
  if (p(node)) {
    return;
  }

  await expandOneNode(node); // this will populate the `children` field asynchronously

  const promises = node.children!.map(r => expandToNode(r, p));
  await Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Some dummy structures for demo purposes:

```js
// This is just a dummy interface for demo purposes, yours is different.
interface TreeNode {
  id: string;
  children?: TreeNode[];
  data?: any;
}

// Simulate async expansion of node that takes 1 second to complete
async function expandOneNode(node: TreeNode): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      node.children = []; // just an example
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

Usage:

```js
await expandToNode(root, n => n.data?.foundGold); // dummy criterion for demo purposes
```